# EMDK Android Studio

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, symbols, barcode-scanner

Can someone help me....

I cant recive intent from Symbol TC75 scanner. I have setup profile that sends intent to my app my app recive null intent.

I have put this code in mainfest file....

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk"/>

<activity
        android:name=".aufladen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking.BARCODE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in onCreate i put this

```
EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.getEMDKManager(this.getApplicationContext(), this);


    if(results.statusCode == STATUS_CODE.FAILURE)
    {
        //Failed to create EMDKManager object
    }
    Intent i = getIntent();
    handleDecodeData(i);


@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
    handleDecodeData(i);
}

private void handleDecodeData(Intent i) {
    if (i.getAction().contentEquals("com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking.BARCODE")) {
        String data = i.getStringExtra("com.motorolasolutions.emdk.datawedge.data_string");

        if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

After i play this app on real device i get this error in log

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking, PID: 5163
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking/com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking.aufladen}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'boolean
>   java.lang.String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                                                      at
>   com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking.aufladen.handleDecodeData(aufladen.java:610)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.draganm.mpreiscontainertracking.aufladen.onCreate(aufladen.java:101)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6012)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Comment: `i.getAction()` is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confusing the different ways to retrieve scanned data.  Intents are only sent from the DataWedge service (http://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-0/guide/about/) but you are also initialising the EMDK library (http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-0/guide/gettingstarted/).  EMDK returns its data via callback.

If you choose the DataWedge route, I have an application which listens for DataWedge intents that might help: https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedge-API-Exerciser

If you choose the EMDK route, there are samples on Zebra's own site: http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-0/samples/barcode/

Comment: After days of searching i found solution ..... I must insert super.onNewIntent in onNewIntent methode

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent i) {
    super.onNewIntent(i);
    handleDecodeData(i);
}

But your answer helped me more to understand this thank you :)